# Has my link register gone wrong?

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, arm

I am debugging a piece of software on an ARM chip via GDB. After loading the program (and before running it), when I do `info registers` I get:

```
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x0      0
r1             0x0      0
r2             0x0      0
r3             0x0      0
r4             0x0      0
r5             0x0      0
r6             0x0      0
r7             0x0      0
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0x4770   0x4770
lr             0xffffffff       4294967295
pc             0x8005dc5        0x8005dc5 <Reset_Handler+1>
fps            0x0      0
cpsr           0x20     32
```

The one register I find worrisome is `lr` set to `0xffffffff`. I am thinking this may be the reason for my crash.

Is it normal to have `lr` initiated to `0xffffffff`?

Comment: In the current function, does the compiler reuse lr for another purpose,and restore it later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a situation where you have the debugger stopping execution very shortly after reset (I'm basing this on your description and the symbol name associated with the `PC` value).  If so, don't worry about the inital state of `lr` - just don't use it until you've initialized it (which probably wouln't make much sense anyway until it was explicitly set by your assembly code or by the C compiler to handle a function call).

Since another person guessed that you were using a Cortex-M3 processor, here's some of what the Technical Reference Manual says about the processor's behavior at reset:

> 5.9 Resets
>
> The NVIC is reset at the same time as the core and controls the
>   release of reset into the  core. As a result, the behavior of reset is
>   predictable. Table 5-7 shows the reset behavior. For more information
>   about resets, see Chapter 6 Clocking and Resets.
>
> Table 5-7 Reset actions
>
> ```
> Action                                Description
> =================================   ====================================================
>
> NVIC resets, holds core in reset    NVIC clears most of its registers. The processor is 
>                                     in Thread mode, priority is privileged, and the stack 
>                                     is set to Main.
>
> NVIC releases core from reset       NVIC releases core from reset.
>
> Core sets stack                     Core reads the start SP, SP_main, from vector-table offset 0.
>
> Core sets PC and LR                 Core reads the start PC from vector-table offset. 
>                                     LR is set to 0xFFFFFFFF.
>
> Reset routine runs                  NVIC has interrupts disabled, and NMI and Hard Fault 
>                                     are not disabled.
> ```

So if you're running an M3, that's why `lr` is set to `0xffffffff`.

I don't see any mention of how the other general purpose registers are initialized at reset - I wouldn't count on them being zero. Initialize them yourself.

If you're not running an M3, the ["What values are in ARM registers after a power-on reset?" note](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3761.html) may apply to your device. It says:

> Registers `R0` - `R14` (including banked registers) and `SPSR` (in all modes) are undefined after reset.

(`r14` is `lr`).

Answer (score 3):

lr is the Link Register. It only contains a value *after* the program has executed a function call. It contains the value of the return address. On ARM, the most recent return address is in the lr register rather than on the stack, which saves two memory accesses, and hence is much faster than pushing the return address into memory, onto the stack, then pulling it back off to return.

lr might be deliberately set to that value so that the processor can detect a fault if it ever gets loaded back into the program counter.

Can you step through the code to the first function call, enter it, and see it change?

What system is it? is it a deeply embedded microcontroller, or something with an operating system?

The stack pointer looks quite low. It's value depends on the processor. It is usually set to point at the top of RAM. It might be a bit less because the system has put some stuff above it. But, that is only 18,288 Bytes for stack, and it is normally above global and static variables, and even above the heap. It may be correct, it just depends on the processor.

For a comparison, on the mid-density family of STM32103, which is an embedded processor, RAM is 0x20000000 to 0x20005000

Answer (score 0):

is this a cortex-m?  that looks like a return value when you are in an interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

0xffffffff is Considered the Reset Value of the Link Register so I think that this might be some early steps of debugging and No its not the reason of crash this is a normal value to see